# simplify a join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the most stars per employee department, so from table csereduxresponses add the stars from each department and then divide that using the employee.cse_dept (#of employee in each department). The employedept=dept_id, employee=emp_id.
I made a mock tables to simplify.

```
    create table csereduxresponds  (employeedept int, employee int, stars int);

insert into csereduxresponds  values(1,1,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(1,1,0);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(1,1,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(1,2,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(1,2,0);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(3,3,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(3,3,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(4,3,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(4,3,0);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(4,3,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(4,3,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(5,4,0);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(5,4,1);
insert into csereduxresponds  values(5,4,1);

create table employee ( dept_id int,emp_id int,cse_dept int);

insert into employee values (1,1,14);
insert into employee values (1,2,14);
insert into employee values (3,3,8);
insert into employee values (5,4,9);
insert into employee values (6,5,10);

create table csereduxdepts(csedept_id int, dept_name varchar(25));
insert into  csereduxdepts(1,'dapartmen one');
insert into  csereduxdepts(2,'dapartmen two');
insert into  csereduxdepts(3,'dapartmen 3');
insert into  csereduxdepts(4,'dapartmen 4');
insert into  csereduxdepts(5,'dapartmen 5');
insert into  csereduxdepts(6,'dapartmen 6');
```

I have this query that does something similar , where it gets the total_stars of each employee, but not by department:

```
  select a.employee, a.execoffice_status,a.employeedept, b.csedept_id as department_id , b.csedept_name as department_name,
  SUM(execoffice_status) as total_stars,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(execoffice_status)desc )as rnk
  from intranet.dbo.CSEReduxResponses a join intranet.dbo.CSEReduxDepts b
  on b.csedept_id = a.employeedept
  group by employee,execoffice_status,employeedept,csedept_id,csedept_name
  order by rnk
```

I forgo to add another table which has the department names.
Here I want to ouput the department name and the stars/cse_dept

Comment: Could you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, here's an aggregation of the stars per employee per department, divided by the static value of employee's per department (`cse_dept`).  The PerCSE is shown as a percentage.

```
SELECT  employeedept
      , employee
      , SUM(stars) NumStars
      , MAX(cse_dept) EmployeeDeptCount
      , SUM(stars) * 100.00 / MAX(cse_dept) AS PerCSE
FROM    employee e
JOIN    csereduxresponds c
        ON employeedept = dept_id
           AND employee = emp_id
GROUP BY employeedept
      , employee
```

Here's the join per the conditions provided.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employee e
JOIN    csereduxresponds c
        ON employeedept = dept_id
           AND employee = emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
( 

select employeedept
, employe From employee e 
)
Select c.employeedept
, c.employe
, SUM(cc.stars) NumStars
, MAX(cc.cse_dept) EmployeeDeptCount
, SUM(cc.stars) * 100.00 / MAX(cc.cse_dept) AS PerCSE
 From CTE C
INNER JOIN csereduxresponds cc
ON C.employeedept = cc.dept_id
AND C.employee = CC.emp_id
```